# Как получить разницу двух полей таблицы Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, framework

У меня стоит задача такого плана. Есть число(например 5000) и есть таблица с данными, в строках есть поля balance и revers в каждом из этих полей числа, например в поле balance значение 10000, а в поле revers значение 20000 и мне необходимо одним запросом в таблицу получить именно те строки где разница balance и revers составляет больше либо равно 5000. Заранее благодарен за ответ. Фреймворк Laravel 4.2

Comment: И в чём проблема-то? не знаете, какой математической операцией считается разница значений? или какой оператор сравнения использовать для поставленной задачи? Если поле разности нужно в списке вывода - добавьте как RAW, и выполните отбор по нему в `->having` (если, конечно, фреймворк не заартачится использовать его без группировки). Иначе - просто используйте RAW-условие во `->where`.

Comment: Я пытался сделать что то 
$sums = '5000';
$result = Dok::selectRaw('(balance - revers) as results')->get(); но вот не могу понять как сделать условие

Comment: Такой вот запрос $result = Dok::where(sum('balance - revers'),' >', 10000)->get(); вообще бьет ошибку

Comment: У тебя агрегатная функция? предупреждать надо! тогда какой нафиг WHERE? проверку результата агрегатной функции делается только и исключительно в HAVING. И это... я не вижу группировки - а без неё у тебя запрос просуммирует всю таблицу в одно значение. PS. А с синтаксисом фреймворка борись самостоятельно - я его не использую.

Comment: Пробовал  $result = Dok::having('(balance +revers)',' >', 10000)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
Выдает ошибку что SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(balance + revers)' in 'having clause' (SQL: select * from `dok` where `dok`.`deleted_at` is null having `(balance + revers)` > 10000 order by `id` desc)

Comment: Ребят, помогите хоть написать сырой запрос, вообще никак не могу сообразить